# Problema con loop en código

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código que muestra los horoscopos, pero se me esta disparando el display:block y none de seguido entonces se ve como titilando el texto y no se desaparece, que debo corregir?

```js
var horoscopo = null;

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.responseType = 'json';
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        horoscopo = this.response.horoscopo;
        //document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = this.response.horoscopo.escorpion.amor;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.adderou.cl/tyaas/", true);
xhttp.send();

var horoscopo = null;


var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.responseType = 'json';
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        horoscopo = this.response.horoscopo;
        //document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = this.response.horoscopo.escorpion.amor;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.adderou.cl/tyaas/", true);
xhttp.send();


var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
video.ontimeupdate = function () {
    myFunction()
};


function myFunction() {

    var content = document.getElementById('content-text');
    var content2 = document.getElementById('content-text2');
    
    if (video.currentTime >= 1 && video.currentTime <= 9) {
    document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = horoscopo.aries.nombre + ' : ' + horoscopo.aries.amor;
    } else if (video.currentTime >= 9 && video.currentTime <= 16) {
        document.getElementById('content-text2').innerText = horoscopo.tauro.nombre + ' : ' + horoscopo.tauro.amor;
         content.style.display = (content.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    } else if (video.currentTime >= 17 && video.currentTime <= 24) {
        document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = horoscopo.geminis.nombre + ' : ' + horoscopo.geminis.amor;
        content2.style.display = (content2.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    } else if (video.currentTime >= 25 && video.currentTime <= 33) {
        document.getElementById('content-text2').innerText = horoscopo.cancer.nombre + ' : ' + horoscopo.cancer.amor;
        content.style.display = (content.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    } else if (video.currentTime >= 34 && video.currentTime <= 41) {
        document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = horoscopo.leo.nombre + ' : ' + horoscopo.leo.amor;
        content2.style.display = (content2.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    } else if (video.currentTime >= 42 && video.currentTime <= 49) {
        document.getElementById('content-text2').innerText = horoscopo.virgo.nombre + ' : ' + horoscopo.virgo.amor;
       content.style.display = (content.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    } else if (video.currentTime >= 49 && video.currentTime <= 57) {
        document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = horoscopo.libra.nombre + ' : ' + horoscopo.libra.amor;
        content2.style.display = (content2.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    } else if (video.currentTime >= 57 && video.currentTime <= 65) {
        document.getElementById('content-text2').innerText = horoscopo.escorpion.nombre + ' : ' + horoscopo.escorpion.amor;
        content.style.display = (content.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    } else if (video.currentTime >= 65 && video.currentTime <= 73) {
        document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = horoscopo.sagitario.nombre + ' : ' + horoscopo.sagitario.amor;
        content2.style.display = (content2.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    } else if (video.currentTime >= 73 && video.currentTime <= 81) {
        document.getElementById('content-text2').innerText = horoscopo.capricornio.nombre + ' : ' + horoscopo.capricornio.amor;
        content.style.display = (content.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    } else if (video.currentTime >= 81 && video.currentTime <= 89) {
        document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = horoscopo.acuario.nombre + ' : ' + horoscopo.acuario.amor;
        content2.style.display = (content2.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    } else if (video.currentTime >= 89) {
        document.getElementById('content-text2').innerText = horoscopo.piscis.nombre + ' : ' +  horoscopo.piscis.amor;
        content.style.display = (content.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="content-text">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="content-text2">&nbsp;</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cómo estás llamando el script?

Comment: Mira ya esta el código completo

Comment: Estás llamando a la función dentro de un evento ontimeupdate, así que se ejecutará repetidamente durante toda la reproducción del vídeo. Dentro de la función alternas el estado del display, por lo que obviamente generará un efecto parpadeo. Explica cuál sería el comportamiento esperado o aporta el html para que el código pueda probarse.

Comment: Listo ya esta el HTML

Comment: El comportamiento esperado es que salga de a un solo horoscopo, pero uno arriba y otro abajo, como en dos contenedores.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si entendí bien, pero a ver si es esto lo que buscas:

```
function myFunction() {

    var content = document.getElementById('content-text');
    var content2 = document.getElementById('content-text2');

    var contenido, contenedor;

    if (video.currentTime <= 9) {
        contenido = horoscopo.aries;
        contenedor = content;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 16) {
        contenido = horoscopo.tauro;
        contenedor = content2;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 24) {
        contenido = horoscopo.geminis;
        contenedor = content;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 33) {
        contenido = horoscopo.cancer;
        contenedor = content2;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 41) {
        contenido = horoscopo.leo;
        contenedor = content;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 49) {
        contenido = horoscopo.virgo;
        contenedor = content2;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 57) {
        contenido = horoscopo.libra;
        contenedor = content;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 65) {
        contenido = horoscopo.escorpion;
        contenedor = content2;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 73) {
        contenido = horoscopo.sagitario;
        contenedor = content;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 81) {
        contenido = horoscopo.capricornio;
        contenedor = content2;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 89) {
        contenido = horoscopo.acuario;
        contenedor = content;
    } else {
        contenido = horoscopo.piscis;
        contenedor = content2;
    }

    contenedor.innerText = contenido.nombre + ' : ' + contenido.amor;

    content.style.display = contenedor==content ? 'block' : 'none';
    content2.style.display = contenedor==content2 ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Comment: Mira si es así, pero necesito que cuando salga uno se desaparezca el otro, me hago entender ?

Comment: Que salga uno abajo y desaparezca, que salga uno arriba y desaparezca y así, uno arriba, uno abajo, uno arriba uno abajo así, de a uno.

Comment: Actualizado en las 2 últimas líneas de la función

Comment: Lo pongo en cada una? que pena

Comment: Mira la imagen, siguen apareciendo así, no se oculta el anterior

Comment: Ponlo tal cual lo puse en el código, abajo del todo

Comment: por ejemplo sale aries de primero y cuando sale tauro arriba se queda aries abajo, necesito es que desaparezca el anterior.

Comment: Cierto perdón, hay que llamar a `.style.display` para cambiar el estado. Actualizo el script.

Comment: La verdad te lo agradezco demasiado, ya me funciono le faltaba el style, muchas gracias.